# Manual network interface names work for Wi-Fi but not for Ethernet device

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, network-interface

I'm running Debian 9.
I've been following [this guide](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) to assign manual network interface names.
I've created two files:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/network/20-wlan0.link 
[Match]
MACAddress=e0:94:67:0a:aa:f0

[Link]
Name=wlan0

$ cat /etc/systemd/network/50-eth0.link 
[Match]
MACAddress=3c:97:0e:06:f0:44

[Link]
Name=eth0
```

After I reboot the system only my the interface for my Wi-Fi card is renamed:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:97:0e:06:f0:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:94:67:0a:aa:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`udevadm info -e` shows me:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0
E: DEVTYPE=wlan
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] (Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN)
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x0084
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=wlxe094670aaaf0
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=wlp3s0
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporate
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporation
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x8086
E: IFINDEX=3
E: INTERFACE=wlan0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/wlan0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4041253


P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x1502
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=e1000e
E: ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/etc/systemd/network/50-eth0.link
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx3c970e06f044
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp0s25
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Wistron InfoComm(Kunshan)Co.,Ltd.
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:19.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_19_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Ethernet controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporation
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x8086
E: IFINDEX=2
E: INTERFACE=enp0s25
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/enp0s25
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1776573
```

Where is obvious that the *.link* file is loaded but for some unknown reasons interface is not renamed.
Do you have any idea what's wrong and how to debug this?

Comment: Do the middle dots serve a purpose?

Comment: @MichaelHomer what middle dots? :D

Comment: title is backwards.  `wlan0` is a manual (non-predictable) name (styled on the traditional interface names), `enp0s25` is a [predictable name](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).